# Pandas save to_csv format not tabbing spaces

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write some data using a panda frame to a .dat file. Saving isnt an issue its formating. I've used sep = '\t' but it only some times places a tab between data.

My code looks like this:

```
data.reindex(columns = ['n','Burn_Gain','V','I','I_smooth']).to_csv(dat_file_path,index = False,
                                                                            header = False, sep = '\t')
```

the resulting data:

```
1.0 1   0.01785000041127    5.435180664063e-06  5.435180664063e-06
1.0 1   0.01934999972582    5.679321289062e-06  5.679321289062e-06
1.0 1   0.02085000090301    5.89599609375e-06   5.89599609375e-06
1.0 1   0.02235000021756    6.11572265625e-06   6.11572265625e-06
1.0 1   0.0238499995321 6.4453125e-06   6.4453125e-06
1.0 1   0.0253500007093 6.658935546875e-06  6.658935546875e-06
1.0 1   0.02685000002384    6.771850585937e-06  6.771850585937e-06
1.0 1   0.02834999933839    7.015991210937e-06  7.015991210937e-06
1.0 1   0.02985000051558    7.232666015625e-06  7.232666015625e-06
```

Why? and how do I fix this?

Im also trying to set up my code so the save data file will have an empty line added in whenever the first column changes values. If anybody has a neater method than using f.readlines() and a loop, please let me know. Thnx!

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example i.e. some of the data that you are using and what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: This looks like correct tabulator spacing to me.

Comment: Your code works. This is just what tabs look like. Notice that on the lines where the 3rd column "starts too early", the value in the second column is shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the `sep='\t` fault, it is just how the file inside the data is displayed or "how it looks" to our eyes. The file itself is already separated by tabs. This is likely due to the number of digits behind decimal point being different.

I would recommend the following code to make all of it standardized (e.g. 3 digits behind the decimal point)

```
data.reindex(columns = ['n','Burn_Gain','V','I','I_smooth']).to_csv('pandasfile.csv', float_format='%.3f')
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought it's the character of tab in the file when you read it in your eyes. but in fact the actual file itself it just save as `\t`:

```
df_str = '''
1.0 1   0.01785000041127    5.435180664063e-06  5.435180664063e-06
1.0 1   0.01934999972582    5.679321289062e-06  5.679321289062e-06
1.0 1   0.02085000090301    5.89599609375e-06   5.89599609375e-06
1.0 1   0.02235000021756    6.11572265625e-06   6.11572265625e-06
1.0 1   0.0238499995321 6.4453125e-06   6.4453125e-06
1.0 1   0.0253500007093 6.658935546875e-06  6.658935546875e-06
1.0 1   0.02685000002384    6.771850585937e-06  6.771850585937e-06
1.0 1   0.02834999933839    7.015991210937e-06  7.015991210937e-06
1.0 1   0.02985000051558    7.232666015625e-06  7.232666015625e-06
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_str.strip()), sep='\s+', index_col=False, header=None)

df.to_csv('t1.csv', sep='\t', header=None)

# !cat t1.csv

list(open('t1.csv'))
# ['0\t1.0\t1\t0.01785000041127\t5.435180664063e-06\t5.435180664063e-06\n',
#  '1\t1.0\t1\t0.01934999972582\t5.679321289062e-06\t5.679321289062e-06\n',
#  '2\t1.0\t1\t0.02085000090301\t5.89599609375e-06\t5.89599609375e-06\n',
#  '3\t1.0\t1\t0.02235000021756\t6.11572265625e-06\t6.11572265625e-06\n',
#  '4\t1.0\t1\t0.0238499995321\t6.4453125e-06\t6.4453125e-06\n',
#  '5\t1.0\t1\t0.0253500007093\t6.658935546875e-06\t6.658935546875e-06\n',
#  '6\t1.0\t1\t0.02685000002384\t6.771850585937e-06\t6.771850585937e-06\n',
#  '7\t1.0\t1\t0.02834999933839\t7.015991210937e-06\t7.015991210937e-06\n',
#  '8\t1.0\t1\t0.02985000051558\t7.232666015625e-06\t7.232666015625e-06\n']
```

[image]